# how to switch off openvpn

Tags: openvpn

Whenever I use openvpn I have to restart the computer to stop it. Closing the command box doesn't stop it, neither does switching off the wifi. Is there a way to switch off the openvpn connection without restarting my computer?

Comment: How do you start OpenVPN?

Comment: I right click the config file then click open in terminal then: sudo openvpn --config (config file info here)

Comment: @displayman You should click the little grey check-mark next to Kyle H's answer turning it to green and that means [this is the correct answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

I usually just run it in a terminal, then go do things in other terminal windows. To kill the connection I go to the terminal window running openvpn, and press Ctrl+C

Comment: You're very welcome! Please indicate my answer as correct for the benefit of googlers with the same issue looking for a solution everywhere! Feel free to post anytime :)

Comment: This answer  'press ctrl+c' is correct

Comment: There's an upvote buttonbat the top left of the post, above 0 :)

Comment: **KyleH**: new users cannot upvote.  They should [accept](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers).  i already left a note to @displayman to do just that.

Answer (score 1):

Please try these commands:

```
sudo service openvpn stop
sudo killall openvpn
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the commands didn't work, however a note from Kyle H advising me to go to the command box and press ctrl+c worked.

Comment: This answer 'press ctrl+c

Comment: This answer 'press ctrl+c' is correct

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/660403)

Comment: Ah, forgot about that. Thank you Fabby. No problem! :)

Comment: @Fabby this is most definitely an attempt to answer the question..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo killall -9 openvpn
```